# Intellij + Database Navigator gives me an error

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2020.2 and trying to install the plugin Database Navigator 3.2.0627.0 with the
Error log: **Plugin Error: Plugin "Database Navigator" is incompatible (until build 201.SNAPSHOT < IC-202.6397.94)**.

BTW, the plug in is not listed on the plugin browser inside Intellij IDEA. The site to dowload it is:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/versions/

I tried other previous versions with the same faulty results.

This is the "About" report from Intellij IDEA

```
Build #IC-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1962M
Cores: 12
Non-Bundled Plugins: GLSL, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv, com.codota.csp.intellij
```

I haven't found any reports or comments regarding this error.
I hope someone can tell me what is wrong with my setup or the plug in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need contact plugin developer Dan Cioca to get help.

All his contacts a mentioned on [the plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/versions/).

Answer (score 0):

try to download it from intellij directlly, go to file => settings => plugins => marketplace => then type database navigator and download it